# How to write a maven plugin without the need to specify executions

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I wrote a maven plugin `latex-maven-plugin` to create pdf or html out of latex sources.

The according entry in a pom is full of executions:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>eu.simuline.m2latex</groupId>
                <artifactId>latex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process-latex-sources-pdf</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>pdf</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process-latex-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>cfg</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>clear-latex-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clr</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <?m2e execute onConfiguration?>
                        <id>validate-converters</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>vrs</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <versionsWarnOnly>true</versionsWarnOnly>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

For example the `ClearMojo` looks like that:

```
@Mojo(name = "clr", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.CLEAN)
public class ClearMojo extends AbstractLatexMojo {
...
}
```

If I understand right, the `defaultPhase` is the one assumed in the according execution

```
                    <execution>
                        <id>clear-latex-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clr</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
```

It is clear, that I **always** want to execute the goal in phase CLEAN.
So I tried to avoid defining an execution in each pom I use the plugin.
I experimented with

```
@Execute( goal = "clr", phase = LifecyclePhase.CLEAN)
```

as a replacement for the execution in the pom.
But this did not work at all.

Maybe I misunderstood the documentation.
What I search is a way to bind a goal to a lifecycle without specifying an execution in the pom.
I feel specifying an execution in the pom is a bad thing
because the goal-phase binding shall not be configurable.
I don't want to write the execution in every single pom.

Who can help me?

A special problem comes into the game with goal `vrs`, version check.
There I want to have different behavior in

- `mvn latex:vrs`: detailed list of versions of `lualatex`, `makeindex`, `mpost`, ...
- `mvn deploy` just a warning if **any** version is out of a predefined range.

I solved the problem by specifying `<versionsWarnOnly>true</versionsWarnOnly>` in the pom (see above)
for default phase validate:

```
@Mojo(name = "vrs", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.VALIDATE)
public class VersionMojo extends AbstractLatexMojo {
...
}
```

I am looking forward to suggestions.

Comment: The simple answer to that is: You can not avoid the execution block in general. As you already mentiond you can omit the phase based on the defaultPhase... The usage of `@Execute` is so called forking the life cycle which you should avoid...because it's not what you want... if I correctly understand. The other part `mvn latex:vrs` vs. `mvn deploy` can be achieved by using a configuration for command line execution and the other configuration bound to life cycle...

Comment: @khmarbaise Oh, means what I wrote is quite state of the art.. hm... 
I must admit I am not so confident.. because.. I think most plugins will be executed always in the same phase. So, It would be better to have a mechanism to tie to a phase once programmatically then each project in a pom configuration. 
This is a real weakness...

Comment: Could you you point me on some documentation about forking? I have no notion about it. Unfortunately @execute by its mere name does not give any indication that it is about forking..

Comment: You might not confident...you seemed to misunderstand that a number of plugins is defined via the life cycle (like maven-compiler-plugin, maven-resources-plugin etc. see https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.9.2/maven-core/default-bindings.html) You might want to have a different appropach, but at the moment it is the way it is. Apart from that you could attach your plugin in particular phases once (via a parent pom) and then simply inherit from that parent pom?

Comment: @khmarbaise... yes.. i realize that some very common plugins are tied hardcoded to phases of lifecycle... Well, I think, nevertheless, for most self written plugins and within them for most goals the standard lifecycle makes sense and there is a single phase it is always tied to. 
This means that it makes more sense not to tie the goal to the phase in the pom but already in the implementation of the plugin. 
But you explained to me that this is not possible at the moment.

Comment: You seemed to be mixing here some concepts. A default binding which a plugin can define if it makes sense and the general binding to the life cycle are two different things. The default binding means the life cycle phase to which a plugin is bound (via plugin itself). That mean in binding you don't define the phase but you have to bind the goal at least...

Comment: I agree that there are two concepts. I did not mix up. I just stated, that i think in many cases there is a kind of default goal which is intended to be always executed. 
I just wanted to make life of applier simpler. 
You convinced me that there is no way, and maybe, it is  not that important. 
in the special case, I think the state as is is acceptable.